# Error trying to add a custom dll to report builder 3.0

Tags: c#, dll, reporting-services

I have a custom DLL which helps me add a barcode to a report. I have added this dll to  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Report Builder3.0

The report works great on my machine connected to the server, but on client machine, I get this error:
[image]

I have used all the same settings that I have on my machine - everything is the same but I am still getting this error. Can anyone see where I am going wrong?

Comment: Have you copied the barcode dll across to the client machine? How are you installing the application on the client?

Comment: hello Darren , yes i have copied the barcode dll to the same location on the clients machine c-> PF -> Microsoft SQL Server\Report Builder3.0 it is there... i have also copied to visual studio-> private assemblies . should i install it on the GAC?

Comment: i have done all the steps from this excellent article : http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/789254/How-to-embed-Barcodes-in-your-SSRS-report

Comment: Yea, it wouldn't hurt being in the GAC

Answer (score 0):

if you add dll in
**C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SQL Server\Report Builder3.0**
folder,this may help you solve problem only in current system where report builder is located but if you solved this problem at report server level then you may add this dll to 
**Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\MSRS12.MSSQLSERVER\Reporting Services\ReportServer\bin**
folder also.